# Live search in jQuery and highlight search results

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a faq page with live search - search results are hidden and appear as the user types. The script below works well, except I want to highlight the searched text as the user types.

**HTML**

```
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<fieldset>
   Search: <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" name="filter" value="" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="content-block">
            <div class="faq">
                <div class="arrow right"></div>
                <div class="question">
                    Can I send Greek characters?
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    The systems support so-called Unicode messages, but because this concerns an extended
                    character set the message is limited to 70 characters.
                </div>
            </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#filter").keyup(function(){

// Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
if(!filter){
    //$(".commentlist li").hide();
    $(".answer").hide();
    return;
}

var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
// Loop through the comment list
//$(".commentlist li").each(function(){
$(".answer").each(function(){

    // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
    if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        //$(this).hide();
        $(this).fadeOut('slow')

    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
    } else {
        //$(this).show();
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        count++;
    }
});

// Update the count
var numberItems = count;
$("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
});
});
```

Demo of script in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mrynart/buw23asn/5/

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, why don't you just use an existing and popular plugin like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)?

Comment: Thanks james, I found a solution myself for the highlighted search text. You can find the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mrynart/buw23asn/14/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem with the code below.
Live search now shows search results as the user types and highlight the searched text as the user types.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

var $filter = $("#filter"),
    $answer = $(".answer");

$filter.keyup(function(){

// Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
if(!filter){
    $answer.hide();
    return;
}

var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
// Loop through the comment list
$answer.each(function(){

            var pageText = $(this).text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>"),
            searchedText = $filter.val(),
            theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm"),
            newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");

    // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
    if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        $(this)
            .fadeOut('slow')
            .attr("data-open", false);

    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
    } else {
        $(this)
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .attr("data-open", true);

        $(this).html(newHtml);

        count++;
    }
});

// Update the count
var numberItems = count;
$("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
});
});
```

Find the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mrynart/buw23asn/14/